# Multiple destroy in a many to many relation in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to delete some tokens that belongs to a user in a many to many relation. This token has a `key_id` column which is a foreign key to `key.id`.

I've got my `user` and the idea is to get his tokens, and it works fine with `user.getTokens()` but I want to delete these tokens where the `key_id` is the same as the key id stored in `res.apiKey.id`.

It might be easier to understand with what I had in mind in code :

```
user.getTokens().then(function(tokens){
    tokens.destroy({
        where: {key_id: res.apiKey.id}
    }
})
```

And this doesn't work of course. I spent several hours trying to figure it out, but I'm still stuck.

What would be the best solution to achieve this ?

Thank you !

Comment: tokens is an array - you should loop through it and call destroy on each element

Comment: Thanks @JanAagaardMeier it did the trick, I used async lib so I can have an async forEach. I hoped there was a better way, but it works just fine.